# file size not showing correct in android

Tags: android

I am using print writer and fileoutputstream to write a file in android async task using following function:

```
public static  void saveFileToExternalMemoryAsync(Context context,String fileName, String json)throws Exception{
       File AppPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PDMA/DMAPPOutputs/");
       if (!AppPath.exists()) {
           AppPath.mkdirs();
       }
       File outputFile = new File(AppPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName + ".dmapp");
       if (!outputFile.exists())
           outputFile.createNewFile();

       MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] {AppPath.toString(),outputFile.toString()}, null, null);
       FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true);
       PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileOutputStream);
       try{
           pw.println(json);
           pw.flush();
           pw.close();
           fileOutputStream.flush();
           fileOutputStream.close();
       }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }finally{
           pw.flush();
           pw.close();
           fileOutputStream.flush();
           fileOutputStream.close();

           MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] {AppPath.toString(),outputFile.toString()}, null, null);
       }


   }
```

problem is that when I try to copy this file by connecting mobile to pc in mtp, its not copied fully. If I right click to see its size, its less than actual. Now If in android, I copy and paste this file somewhere else, say in downloads folder, size is correct and file is also complete.

What can be the problem.

UPDATE:

If I use fileOutputStream to write bytes one by one , then file is generated but I have to close application to access this file from pc.

Comment: You should only invoke the media scanner only once AFTER you wrote to the file.

Comment: `if (!outputFile.exists())
           outputFile.createNewFile();`. Remove those lines. It's useless. The file will be created by the new file output stream.

Comment: `AppPath.mkdirs();`. Check the return value!
       }`

Comment: directories are created. file is also created. problem is in copying this file to pc.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that by adding this.cancel(true) at the end of onPostExecute() solved problem in my case.

Comment: this should be in comment.